# Android kotlin - app do not show me toast

Tags: android, kotlin

I want when someone insert more than 3 number in month input, the Toast should show a error message, I try it and the app do nothing! Why?(*I am beginner*)
another question how can I use try and catch with that?

```
@SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
fun onClickButton(view: View){

    getAGE.setOnClickListener {
        val Get_year_input = age_year_input.text.toString().toInt()
        val getCurrentYear = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR)
        val finish_year_input = Get_year_input - getCurrentYear
        val getCurrentMonth = Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH)
        val finish_month_input = age_month_input.text.toString().toInt()-getCurrentMonth

        if (age_month_input.length() > 2) {                
            Toasty.error(this,"لقد أدخلت شهر غير صالح",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)  
        } else {
            ShowYearInput.text = " عُمرك الميلادي هو : $finish_year_input و $finish_month_input  أشهر "
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: all your objects should have lower-case names. please stick to the conventional format.

Answer (score 2):

At the end of this block of code:
               `Toasty.error(this,"لقد أدخلت شهر غير صالح",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)`
You are missing `.show()` to show a Toast. Plus add in the post that you are using 3rd party libraries, not all people know `Toasty`.
Normal `Toast` from Android you can set up by this method:
`Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "text", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()`

Answer (score 1):

Just try this:

```
Toast.makeText(applicationContext, "لقد أدخلت شهر غير صالح", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
```

That is what you need :)

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation of Toasty](https://github.com/GrenderG/Toasty)

> Each method always returns a Toast object, so you can customize the
>   Toast much more. **DON'T FORGET THE show() METHOD!**
>   [...]
>
> `Toasty.error(yourContext, "This is an error toast.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT, true).show();`

So the beginner lesson here is: [RTFM!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RTFM)

Usage of try-catch example :

```
try{ 
    val finish_month_input = age_month_input.text.toString().toInt()-getCurrentMonth 
    ShowYearInput.text = " عُمرك الميلادي هو : $finish_year_input و $finish_month_input  أشهر " 
} catch( e : NumberFormatException ){ 
    Toasty.error(this,"لقد أدخلت شهر غير صالح",Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
}
```